# Select Prev row in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to select previous table row using jquery. Any how I managed to select the next row. 
When i click next it will move to next table row but when i click Back it is not working

here is my code

```
<input type="button" id="selectnextrow" value="Next" />
<input type="button" id="selectprerow" value="Back" />
<table id="table">
    <tr class="tablerow"><td>ABC</td></tr>
    <tr class="tablerow"><td>Xyz</td></tr>
    <tr class="tablerow"><td>123</td></tr>
</table>

<script>
    $(function(){
        var rows = $('#table .tablerow');
        var i = 0;
        $('#selectnextrow').click(function()
        {
            if( !$(rows[i]).length ){
                i = 0;
            }
            $('#table .tablerow').css('backgroundColor', '#fff');
            $(rows[i]).css('backgroundColor', '#ddd');
            i = i+1;
        });
        $('#selectprerow').click(function()
        {
            if( !$(rows[i]).length ){
                i = 0;
            }
            $('#table .tablerow').css('backgroundColor', '#fff');
            $(rows[i]).css('backgroundColor', '#ddd');
            i = i-1;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? Error, wrong row selected or nothing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to subtract the from `i` at the beginning of the back button handler:

```
$('#selectprerow').click(function() {
    i = i - 1;
    if (!$(rows[i]).length) {
        i = 0;
    }
    $('#table .tablerow').css('backgroundColor', '#fff');
    $(rows[i]).css('backgroundColor', '#ddd');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Rory McCrossan it worked for me. But I need to click back button two times to go back one step for very first time. Later it will traverse on single clicks. Any idea why??

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {     

    $(function () {
        var rows = $('#table .tablerow');
        var i = 0;

        $('#selectnextrow').click(function () {

            if ($('#table_1').find('tr.selected').length == 0) {
                $('#table_1 tr:first').addClass("selected");
            }
            else {
                i = $('#table_1').find('tr.selected').index() + 1;
                if (i == $('#table_1').find('tr').length)
                {
                    i = 0;
                }
                $('#table_1').find('tr.selected').removeClass("selected")
                $('#table_1 tr:eq('+i+')').addClass("selected");
                }
        });
        $('#selectprerow').click(function () {

            if ($('#table_1').find('tr.selected').length == 0) {
                $('#table_1 tr:first').addClass("selected");
            }
            else {
                if (i == 0) {
                    i = $('#table_1').find('tr').length;
                }
                i = $('#table_1').find('tr.selected').index() - 1;

                $('#table_1').find('tr.selected').removeClass("selected")
                $('#table_1 tr:eq(' + i + ')').addClass("selected");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
 <style>
    .selected {
        background-color:yellow;
    }

</style>
```